# Fill a column with all dates in a month based on cell reference

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Is it possible to use a drop-down menu in Google Sheets as a reference for getting all dates in a month?

I have a drop-down menu in cell A3 that lets me select the year (2018/2019) and I have a drop-down menu in cell A4 that lets me select the month (Jan/Feb/Mar/etc.). Could I use these as a reference to get all the dates in that month?

I can do this by creating a lookup and referencing it but I was hoping that someone could give me a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&DATE(A3, MONTH(A4&1), 1)):
 INDIRECT("A"&EOMONTH(DATE(A3, MONTH(A4&1), 1), 0)))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, its perfect!